# Local to global complexity of triangulations

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, manifolds, 4-manifolds, computational-topology

Alright 3rd time's the charm - editing again to put all my cards on the table.

Consider a PL $n$-manifold $M$. Define the *complexity* $c(M)$ of $M$ to be the minimum number of $n$-simplices needed to triangulate $M$.

For $n>2$ getting lower bounds on $c(M)$ is a difficult problem. I am interested in the particular case where $M$ is a closed, orientable, simply-connected 4-manifold. It is conjectured that $c(M)$ is bounded below by $2\chi(M)-2$. To prove this, I wonder if we can take a "local-to-global" type argument in the sense that I will explain as follows.

Fix a triangulation $\mathcal{T}$ of $M$. For a vertex $V$ of $\mathcal{T}$, consider the *link of $V$*: $\mathrm{lk}(V)$ -- this is the boundary of a regular neighbourhood of $V$. Suppose the $f$-vector (the vector whose $i$th entry is the number of $i$-simplices in the given complex) of $\mathrm{lk}(V)$ is $(v,e,f,t)$. Now consider the *star of $V$*, which is a regular neighbourhood of $V$. This can be realised as $\mathrm{st}(V)\cong C(\mathrm{lk}(V))$, where $C(K)$ is a cone over over $K$. If we write the $f$-vector of $\mathrm{st}(V)$ as $(v',e',f',t',p')$, then since the star is the cone of the link, we have $$(v',e',f',t',p')=(v+1,e+v,f+e,t+f,t),$$ (this can be readily seen by considering how the cone over something is constructed) where the $v,e,f,t$ come from the $f$-vector of $\mathrm{lk}(V)$.

Now note the following:

1. Since $\mathrm{lk}(V)$ is a closed 3-manifold, we have that $f=2t$.
2. The number of tetrahedra $t$ in $\mathrm{lk}(V)$ is equal to the degree of $V$ in $\mathcal{T}$.
3. Hence, the number of pentachora (4-simplices) $p'$ in $\mathrm{st}(V)$ is also equal to $\deg(V)$.

Let me now define the quantity $X(K):=v-e+f$ for any $n$-dimensional complex $K$ with $n\geq 2$. From the $f$-vector of $\mathrm{st}(V)$, we have that $$X(\mathrm{st}(V))=(v+1)-(e+v)+(f+e)=f+1=2t+1=2p'+1=2\deg(V)+1.$$

The lower bound on $c(M)$ I desire could be shown (amongst many other equivalent formulations) if one can show that $$X(\mathcal{T})\leq 2P(\mathcal{T})+1,$$ where $P(\mathcal{T})$ is the number of pentachora in $\mathcal{T}$ (the lower bound comes from bounding the Euler characteristic of $M$, $\chi(M)=X(\mathcal{T})-T(\mathcal{T})+P(\mathcal{T})$)

Now we arrive at the heart of the title of this post: We can see that the "$X(K)\leq 2P(K)+1$" bound holds *locally* on the neighbourhoods of the vertices of $\mathcal{T}$ --- which brings us to my question can we extend this local condition to a global one? i.e. can we use the fact that for all vertices $V$ of $\mathcal{T}$ we have $X(\mathrm{st}(V)\leq 2P(\mathrm{st}(V))+1$ to establish the same $X$ bound on the entirety of $\mathcal{T}$?

Summing $X$ over all $V$ seems promising, and since each pentachoron has 5 vertices, we can divide by 5 to account for (at least some of?) the overcounting in the sum (though I'm not sure whether this accounts for *all* of the overcounting when summing up the $X$ quantities..?) - but I'm not entirely sure how to then tie this sum back to $\chi(M)$, etc.

Or whether we could argue something like "X holds on the vertices, so extending linearly over the simplices of $\mathcal{T}$... something something... the bound holds on all of $\mathcal{T}$"??

Anyway, I think this pretty much covers all the details for my particular case... but again, happy to elaborate on anything if need be.

I will also add finally that all of this conjecture is backed up by extensive "experimental" evidence (i.e. that the $X(\mathcal{T})\leq 2P(\mathcal{T})+1$ bound holds, $2\chi\leq c(M)$, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer to your question unless you're more specific about the kind of property that you're interested in. In general in topology the relationship between the complexity of a combinatorial representation (degree of vertices or number of simplices in a triangulation, crossings in a knot diagram, genus of a Heegard splitting) and other measures of complexity (knot genus, hyperbolic volume, etc.) is a difficult problem.

Comment: As stated, I don’t see why you can’t just sum the local complexity over the vertices to get a global complexity. In its current form, the question seems too vague to answer.

Comment: By the way, the combinatorial Gauss—Bonnet theorem for triangulated surfaces is a nice example of the sort of phenomenon you seem to be talking about. Identify each face with a Euclidean  triangle. Define the curvature of each vertex to be $2\pi$ minus the sum of the angles at the vertex. Then the sum of the curvatures of the vertices is $2\pi$ times the Euler characteristic!

Comment: Your question is too vague to have any answer. But it is attracting enough attention to suggest that this is an interesting area.  You should rewrite to make the question more specific and then you will probably get useful answers.

Comment: Hi all, my apologies for the initial vagueness, I've edited the question to hopefully be a bit more concrete. @HJRW - see my remarks regarding the sum over all verts approach. Also regarding your GB comment - yes this had occurred to me that maybe we could turn this into a geometry problem via (generalised) Chern-Gauss-Bonnet - but then I fear I'd be at even more of loss as to how to proceed haha 

Comment: If I understand your definitions, the "star" of a vertex is always an $n$-ball and thus has "complexity" equal to one.  So $K$ equals one, and so you are hoping to lower bound the complexity of a manifold by "one".

Comment: Ok, the following is true - you can count the number of $n-1$ simplices in all of the stars, add up, divide by $n+1$, and so obtain the number of $n$ simplices in the given triangulation.  (So, if the complexity of the manifold is large, then any triangulation will need either lots of vertices, or some vertices with large stars.)  But this is a combinatorial fact (a version of the hand-shaking lemma), not a topological one...

Comment: Ah ok I just realised from your comment I probably shouldn't be comparing complexities (as I've defined it) like "$K\leq c(\mathrm{St}(v))\Rightarrow K\leq c(M)$"  since as you pointed out, the complexity of the star is 1, and this results in an utterly vacuous statement --- rather I want to compare the number of $n$-simplices (not necessarily the *complexity* of star v) of $\mathrm{St}(v)$ in any triangulation of $M$ to the complexity of M. I'll edit the question to add some more details.

Comment: Ah, in my third comment (just above) I should have said "$n-1$ simplices in all of the links".  This is the same as the number of $n$ simplices in the stars.

Comment: I think that you are silently assuming that your triangulations are simplical.  For example, you don’t allow pseudo-triangulations or $\Delta$-structures?  For, consider doubling a four-simplex across its boundary.  This gives a “triangulation” of the four-sphere with two four-simplices (which is smaller than $2 \chi(S^4)$).

Comment: Oh, and we need “without boundary” as otherwise the four-ball is a counter-example.

Comment: No no not at all, I am specifically using $\Delta$-complexes here - there's an additive constant which I didn't mention in the post because I was trying to highlight the $2\chi$ "order of magnitude" so to speak. The conjectured bound is specifically $2\chi(M)-2$ (which the 2-simplex $S^4$ attains). And yes we're assuming closed here (without boundary).